# How to convert following date format into valid date in Informatica?

Tags: database, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am getting date in following format in a flat file. How do I convert into valid date format (YYYY-MM-DD) in Informatica?

**Input data:**

```
Jan 4, 2016

Feb 2, 2016
```

**Desired Output :**

```
2016-01-04

2016-02-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression in a output column of type String

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(inputField,'MON DD,YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The inner TO_DATE function converts the string 'Jan 4, 2016' to a Date type. Note the format string 'MON DD,YYYY', it is the format in which it is coming from source.

The outer TO_CHAR function converts the Date to a String again in the specified format 'YYYY-MM-DD'